# memory leaks at showing UIKeyboard on ARC

Tags: iphone, ios

When `UIKeyboard` is called, memory is allocated and not freed when `UIKeyboard` is hidden. If it is the framework who is caching it, is there any way to clear it up?
These code is what I use to create the `UITextField` and how I hide the `UIKeyboard`:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface SignInTextField : UITextField

    -(id)initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

    @end

    #import "SignInTextField.h"

    @implementation SignInTextField

    -(id)initWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
                // iPad
                self.frame = CGRectMake(110, 10, 600, 30);
            } else {
                self.frame = CGRectMake(110, 11, 150, 30);
            }

            self.tag = [indexPath row];
            self.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        }
        return self;
    }

    //SettingTextField
    SignInTextField *textField = [[SignInTextField alloc]initWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    textField.delegate = self;

    #pragma mark - Text Field CallBack
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        activeField = textField;
    }

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

        if(textField.tag == 0) temp_email = [NSString         stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];
        if(textField.tag == 1) temp_password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];
    }

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
   }
```

[image: This is leak point.]

Comment: Please, could you show us the code you use?

Comment: What makes you think you have a memory leak? And if you do know, show us your instrument's readings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you open the Keyboard for first time, it is cached by iOS native framework. Its handle by UIKit framework.

Its not the memory leak. Next time onwards when there will be a requirement to display keyboard, application will use cached keyboard.

If the memory requirement goes high, native framework will release the cached views, if required. Still the application needs memory, framework will generate memory warnings for same.